# Стили в php коде (2)

Tags: php

Всем привет, мне надо сделать стили в php коде в **echo ' ';** Пробывал сделать

```
    echo "<span style = \"color: #1faee9; margin-left: 15px; display: blocks;\" >" . $data['name'] . "</span>" . " <img src='../images/left_bottom.png' height='8' width='8'> " . $data['recipient'] . ": " . $data['mess'] ."<br />";
```

Этот скрипт работает нормально, но есть одна проблема. 
Мне надо, чтоб можно было на каждую поставить цвет текста (style), делал вот так:

```
    echo "<span style = \"color: #1faee9; margin-left: 15px; display: blocks;\" >" . $data['name'] . "</span>" . " <img src='../images/left_bottom.png' height='8' width='8'> " "<span style = \"color: #9db1cc;\" >" . $data['recipient'] . "</span>" . ": " . $data['mess'] ."<br />";
```

Выдает ошибку: http://prntscr.com/2igylz

**Весь код:**

```
<?php
    // определяем начальные данные
    $db_host = 'host';
    $db_name = 'name';
    $db_username = 'username';
    $db_password = 'pass';
    $db_table_to_show = 'name-table';

    // соединяемся с сервером базы данных
    $connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
        or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

    // подключаемся к базе данных
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
        or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());

    // выбираем все значения из таблицы "chat"
    $qr_result = mysql_query("select * from " . $db_table_to_show)
        or die(mysql_error());

   // выводим сообщения в чат 
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
    echo "<span style = \"color: #1faee9; margin-left: 15px; display: blocks;\" >" . $data['name'] . "</span>" . " <img src='../images/left_bottom.png' height='8' width='8'> " . $data['recipient'] . ": " . $data['mess'] ."<br />";
    }

    // закрываем соединение с сервером  базы данных
    mysql_close($connect_to_db); 
?>
```

Comment: Вот именно в этом коде пропущена точка (или лишние кавычки) между тегом img и тегом span: ... " <img src='../images/left_bottom.png' height='8' width='8'> <span style = \"color: #9db1cc;\" >" ...

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, напишите скрипт. Мне надо чтоб был такой формат 
Отправитель <img src="..."> получатель: сообщение

цвет поставить на отправителя, получателя, сообщение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<span style = \"color: #1faee9; margin-left: 15px; display: blocks;\" >" . $data['name'] . "</span>" . " <img src='../images/left_bottom.png' height='8' width='8'> "
```

(а вот здесь у вас и есть ошибка, т.к. между кавычками ничего нет, ни знака конкатенации, ни точки с запятой)

```
"<span style = \"color: #9db1cc;\" >" . $data['recipient'] . "</span>" . ": " . $data['mess'] ."<br />";
```

Если использовать IDE с подсветкой кода, то такие ошибки находятся мгновенно.

А еще это можно переписать **красиво**

```
?>
<span style="color: #1faee9; margin-left: 15px; display: block;">
    <?php echo $data['name']; ?>
</span>
<img src="../images/left_bottom.png" height="8" width="8" />
<?php echo "$data[recipient]: $data[mess]"; ?>
<br />
<?php
```

Comment: Нет, выдает ошибку http://prntscr.com/2ims8t